# ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC : errors happening in Autofac not propagated

Tags: c#, exception, autofac

I have an ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC application using Autofac for dependency management with something like this in the `Startup` file :

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterModule(new MyUIModule());

    builder.RegisterBuildCallback(lifetimeScope => AutofacContainer = lifetimeScope);
}
```

I also have in my startup an `app.UseExceptionHandler` to log errors and redirect user to custom error page.

Most of my Autofac registration are just basic constructor calls so no issue here, but for some I have to execute a few line of codes in the `builder.Register<IHttpClientFactory>(ctx => ...` delegate, for example by accessing `IConfiguration` or simple things like that, so those calls are prone to fail and throw exceptions (ex : missing key in `appSettings`).

I have noticed that apparently those exceptions happening during those operations seems to not be logged or propagated anywhere.

The stacktrace looks like

```
    [my custom registration code]
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41_0`1.<Register>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__2_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
```

Of course, I have already added try / catch blocks with logging around these lines, but I would like a structural solution to always be sure to capture those errors without the local try / catch.

Is there any way to capture those errors, with the Autofac API (some kind of "error callback") or in the MVC side (by an error handler) ?
I guess there's a way on Autofac side, but I didn't found it.

Thank you

Comment: This is definitely going to be a "how do I do it in ASP.NET" - Autofac isn't going to "handle resolution exceptions" for you. That may influence your search terms and how you look to solve this.

Comment: The exception is thrown when the dependancy is instantiated by a delegate given to Autofac, so for me Autofac executes it and could allow to do something for exceptions occuring in it... 
And if it's not done at this point, this could also be handled more globally in the app. Please do not hesitate to give your solution as you seem to master the topic.

Comment: I don't have a solution at the moment, so I'm trying to help with what time I have. What I'm trying to say is: Autofac will always throw the exception if there's a problem, just like `new Thing()` constructors will throw. It is 100% up to the application to handle those exceptions - in this case, your app or the ASP.NET framework. There is no provision inside Autofac to swallow, manage, handle, or otherwise deal with those exceptions, and intentionally so. This is common for DI containers. Hence: Look for solutions in the framework, not Autofac/DI - you will have more luck there.

Comment: @TravisIllig Ok, I am fine with this message :). Meanwhile I dig a bit more, the app is mixing 80% of regular MVC Core, and 20% of Blazor Server. The DI error happens during a Blazor operation, and it's not rendered anywhere (despite ErrorBoundary on page and other things). So it's swallowed somewhere by Blazor rendering pipeline, which is highly different than MVC pipeline. And you are right regarding that Autofac is rethrowing the error, it's indeed swallowed by ASP.Net. I'll have to look more to find a way to catch it...